# String to Array with Classic ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I have the following code in Classic ASP:

```
Dim objHttp, strQuery
strQuery = "https://geoip.maxmind.com/f?333l=2112212&i=" & ipaddress
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "GET", strQuery, false
objHttp.send

Response.Write objHttp.ResponseText
Set objHttp = Nothing
```

It's an API from MAxMind to get the city/zip of a user per his IP. It's working but I get a long line like this:

> US,CA,Los Angeles,90068,34.134499,-328.190804,673,818,"AT&T U-verse"

Any idea how can I break this line and take from it certain values?

Comment: [Check the Split function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
theArray = Split(objHttp.ResponseText,",")

for i=0 to uBound (theArray)
  response.write theArray(i)
next
```

Try that. if the string is always in the same format, you can get the 4th element simply by saying `theArray(3)`